# How can I use React.forwardRef with a FontAwesome functional child component in NextJs Link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I am receiving the following error in my console
[image]

I have narrowed this down to the following section in the documentation for Next-Link

[Link here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component)

However I am still unable to resolve the error because in my case the functional child component is a FontAwesomeIcon component, How can I apply this fix to the FontAwesome component?

Code

```
 <div className={styles.linkItem}><Link href='https://github.com/Murchyman' passHref><FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "github"]} /></Link></div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Add an additional `<a>` element to wrap the `FontAwesomeIcon`, i.e. `<Link href='https://github.com/Murchyman'><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "github"]} /></a></Link>`. You won't need to use `passHref` in that case.

Comment: This is the answer, thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad that worked!